# What is the background music played in Psycho-Pass episode 7 at 13:37?

Tags: music, psycho-pass

The background music at 13:37 of episode 7 in Psycho-Pass season 1 is incredible but I am not able to identify it. I already tried music recognition apps like Shazam. They were not able to recognize it. It could be a modified or original version of Beethoven's 9th symphony. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Beethoven's 9th Symphony - Ode to joy. Here is the link to it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wod-MudLNPA